# Extract the array out of an object in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

For my React app, I have a function Query2 in a file service.ts such as:

```
interface Result {
   products: number[];
}

export async function Query2(molsSdf: string): Promise<Result>

{ 
   return  {products: [0.1]}    
}
```

In my component "draw1.jsx" file where I am importing my function Query2, I have these lines of codes:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import {Query2} from '../common-services/service.ts'

const [products, setProductivities] = useState([]);

    async function handleSearch () {

        const mol = window.JSDraw.get("test").getMolfile()

        const pds = await Query2(mol)

        setProductivities(pds)
    }
return ( 
            <div className="button">

                <Button onClick={handleSearch}>Search</Button>      

            </div> 

            <h1>

            {products.map(tox =>

                    <li>
                        Toxs
                    </li>
                )
            }

            </h1>

    );
}

export default Draw1;
```

" const pds = await Query2(mol) " is not getting an array back. I am passing "pds" to "setProductivities as if it's an array, but it's not an array, it's an object. How can I extract the array out of the object "pds" and pass that to setProductivities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your function returns object with products property which is an arry. You need change to this:

```js
  setProductivities(pds.products)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring) the `products` key out of the object which is an array.

```
const { products } = await Query2(mol)
setProductivities(products)
```

You can also alias the destructured key to `pds` (if required).

```
const { products: pds } = await Query2(mol)
setProductivities(pds)
```

Or you can simply access the `products` key from the object, following is one way of doing the same.

```
const pds = (await Query2(mol)).products
setProductivities(pds)
```